# Ionic error: Cordova not defined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use this code:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled) {
   if(!enabled){

   }
   else {

   }
});
```

but show an error in a web bowser:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cordova is not defined

How can I fix this error?

Comment: hi are you sure you've linked all Cordova files? .. have try to test window.cordova?

Comment: if you say like that.                                                                                          Windows. cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled                                           show this error Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined

Comment: where do you run this code? before or after <script src="cordova.js"></script>  have you checked whether this library is inserted?

Comment: @JoaoHenrique `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` will only work on device and only after device is ready event.
Will not work on browser